# Save state of object in IntelliJ debug?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Does anyone know whether it is possible to save the state of an object while debugging?

I would like to compare the state of an object in two different execution cycles.

**Bonus Question:** Anyone with experience in writing IntelliJ plugins? Does the IntelliJ SDK allow to access debug values in debug mode? Read them out of IntelliJ cache and write them to disk?

Comment: I came across question, I'm developing plugin (I'm a rookie) that accesses the selected node in debugger, just to let you know, yes you can access debug data from the debug node. All you need is to write your own `DebugAction` and register it in plugin.xml

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As a very simple solution you can use the *Fully Expand Tree Node* action for objects in *Variables* or *Watches* views. This action is bound to *Numpad ** key (<kbd>*</kbd>) by default and opens the whole object tree. Then you select all the elements of opened object tree with shift and copy them to clipboard.

Comment: You can also use ctrl/cmd-A to select all variables and then copy them.

Comment: Very helpful answer ! Is there a way to copy it and paste to a file as json, xml, yml or csv format?

Comment: @Adamssef don't know the direct way to do it yet, though sometimes I use 'File > New > Scratch file > Json' and paste it there. If a structure is simple, there will be at least some syntax highlights - strings, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 18):

To expand on Josep's answer, your best bet is to import [Google's Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) into your project and run:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

Then copy the value from the result.

Here's an example on IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: example]

Comment: Gson().toJson(repos);

Answer (score 8):

My best workaround to save an object state is to use the Evaluate tool when I have the object in the desired state and using Gson library convert it to a JSON, then at the test setup I copy the JSON as a String and convert it to a Java object again. May be a bit crude but for really large and complex objects it can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Definitely better than copying to plain text. I wish this was an option within the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

In IntelliJ 2016, you have an option to "View Text" when you right click on a variable in "Variables" window while debugging

Comment: this works really good if you select all the values/objects !

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with saving each and every object (you cannot select which objects are saved) then there is a plugin for this:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14974-breakpoint-exporter-importer-with-variable-information

Answer (score 2):

Add below sample code and it will show the data in json form:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  try {
    String sample = mapper.writeValueAsString(Your object);
    System.out.println(sample);
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this, I found something in IntelliJ that wasn't  mentioned here yet.

If you expand the object fields while debugging, then select them all; if you right-click...notice on the screenshot how there's a "Compare value with clipboard".

[image]

What we can do is copy all the class fields in one state to the clipboard, and whenever the state changes, select them all, and choose that option.

It opens up a nice line-by-line comparator, which quickly made me realize that a few properties that were supposed to match, just didn't.

[image]

This mechanism still doesn't provide a true nested comparison (so arrays wouldn't be checked), and the Gson workaround mentioned here makes that more accurate...but in order to avoid adding a library only for this, it can be useful.

I hope it helps!