# Get object as JSON in IntelliJ Idea from debugger

Tags: json, debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to get the whole object from debugger as Json?
There is an option `View text` but can I somehow `View JSON`?

Comment: What a shame that such functionality is not out-of-the-box in IntelliJ IDEA :(

Answer (score 86, accepted):

EDIT: as noted in the comments, this is not perfect, as for some variables you will get a "stackoverflow" response

As suggested by [@Mr Han's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640767/26510), here's how you can do this:

#### Add a new way to view objects in Intellij debugger as json by

- Going to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java Type Renderers`
- Click `+` to add new renderer
- Call it `JSON renderer`
- Supply `java.lang.Object` for `Apply renderer to objects of type`
- Choose `Use following expression:` and supply an expression like so:

```
if (null == this || this instanceof String)
  return this;

new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(this);
```

- Click `OK`
- Now when you choose `Copy Value` on a variable, it will copy as json.
  [image]

Note: If you don't want to change default behaviour, create a "default" renderer also with "use default renderer" settings, and put it first in the list, it will use that as default and you can switch to JSON on demand by right click on debugged variable -> use renderer: JSON Renderer.

Comment: I get sometimes for certain objects, StackOverflow or OutOfMemory exception. Otherwise works like charm. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I see the same @Dileepa - but I think this is true of any approach like this? I tried making the code catch exceptions and return the original "this", but that didnt seem to help

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't work for me, but this does. Also, I like how it's a no plugin solution. Just edit settings, no download plugin hassle.

Comment: I wanted to use the inbuilt feature of IntelliJ for such tasks and this answer does exactly that. Thank god I am not using a plugin for such needs.

Comment: I get the JSON value of the main object but the child object fields are all empty instead of getting copied into JSON

Comment: yeah it's not perfect - i actually don't use it anymore as I found the stack overflow was too annoying

Comment: I get Method threw 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' exception.

Comment: yeah this solution requires the [google gson library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson), and you may be better off going with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69802068/26510) which builds on mine!

Comment: I have the gson library in my project and I'm still getting a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: do you have it as a dev dependency ?

Comment: The code section is not clear, can you format it properly? Despite this I have a bigger issue since I'm getting `Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'com.google.gson.JsonIOException' exception.` a solution that requires a project dependency is hardly a solution to this question imho.

Comment: I get `Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'com.google.gson.JsonIOException' exception`too

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively, as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/arnaudjolly/2ed4d0c7518761129e0439552ac48f9b), you can use the following piece of code in your debug watcher:

```
new ObjectMapper()
    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValueAsString( myObject )
```

Comment: I believe it won't not work for GWT/Client-side debugging

Comment: how we can add the parent element in this case

Answer (score 20):

You can try this code fragment into the Evaluate Expression(Alt + F8) on IntelliJ :

```
new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper() .registerModule(new com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule()) .disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter() .writeValueAsString( myObject );
```

[image IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoftK.png)

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [Show as ...](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7010-show-as--) plugin for IntelliJ.

> A small plugin to display formatted data out of the debugger and console.
>
> Uses IntelliJ's build-in formatting capabilities.
> No more need to copy values from debugger or console to a file to format them there. Following formats are supported: JSON, SQL, XML, Base64 encoded JSON, Base64 encoded text

Comment: Unforunately it soesn't seem to work correctly while debugging as pointed out in the comment section of the plugin. I tried myself without success.

Comment: As people say in the review of the plugin and in multiple comments here on StackOverflow, this plugin does not work (anymore?). What a shame that such functionality is not out-of-the-box in IntelliJ IDEA :(

Answer (score 6):

Just follow it : File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java Type Renderers, click  + to add new render ,
[copy is OK :) u can choose another jar to format it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNnWo.jpg)

And now , Apply, join it ~

Comment: This doesn't seem to print the full object structure.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `gson` dependency in your project you can create a watch variable

```
new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().gson.toJson(myObject)
```

where `myObject` is your object.

Comment: In my case `new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(myObject)` was what worked while debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the [instructions of @BradParks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189764/2886891), and use the following expression.

For me it did not work without fully-qualified class names. I also added some modifications to the `ObjectMapper`. For some reason which I don't understand, even if I have `Apply renderers to object of type` set to `java.lang.Object`, I needed to typecast `this` as `(Object)this` when used as a parameter of the `writeValueAsString()` method.

```java
if (this == null 
|| this instanceof CharSequence 
|| this instanceof Number 
|| this instanceof Character 
|| this instanceof Boolean 
|| this instanceof Enum) {
// Here you may add more sophisticated test which types you want to exclude from the JSON conversion.
    return this;
}

new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper() 
        .registerModule(new com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule())
        .disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .setVisibility(
                com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor.FIELD, 
                JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .setSerializationInclusion(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()         
        .writeValueAsString((Object)this);
```

Comment: Gave me a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @AustinBrown on which of the classes?
I would also *guess* that the jackson library must be included in your project in order this to work.

Comment: It's on the jackson library. I do have the jackson library in my project, but for some reason I still get the exception.

Comment: @AustinBrown On which class exactly? I noticed that in my code the `JsonAutoDetect` class is not fully qualified (but it worked for me) - could this be the problem?

Comment: implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.2")

Answer (score 2):

Use Intellij plugin **Debug Variable Extractor**
More information -
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16362-debug-variable-extractor

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32928993)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I have already provided Intellij plugin name in my answer. Any one can search this plugin and install it. No need to navigate to the link.

Comment: It gives me Timeout on the first run, but when I try again it works very well!
This is the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is having hard time to make the renderers work for more complex objects - below you can find a combined JSON renderer from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189764/3837638
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69802068/3837638
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060407/3837638

The following renderer helped me to identify multiple fields with the same name in the class hierarchy, so I could change that.

Initially I was having IllegalArgumentException for serialization of a nested object that I wasn't able to analyse.

If there is an issue during serialization, with this renderer you can find the stack trace from the exception that you need to fix in the console.

Good luck!

---

```
if (null == this)
    return "null";

if (this instanceof CharSequence
        || this instanceof Number
        || this instanceof Character
        || this instanceof Boolean
        || this instanceof Enum) {
    // Here you may add more sophisticated test which types you want to exclude from the JSON conversion.
    return this;
}
try {
    String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(this);
    return json;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

worked for me:
rightclick on the variable itself to select "Evaluate Expression"

In the popup with the evaluated expression you can right click the result and select "Copy JSON"