# How to export springframework variables while debugging in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: json, debugging, intellij-idea, serialization, gson

i am debugging a target that uses springframework. i want to save the "container" or the "context" -which is inside the later- as xml or json.
i tried several plugins and Gson but they cant handle custom types.

i found this piece of code which works great with simple types:
`new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson( MY_OBJ );`

but it needs TypeAdapter to be able to parse "context" object which is of type "AnnotationConfigApplicationContext"

error:
Failed making field 'java.lang.module.Configuration#parents' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.

searching spring documentation; there are some "serialize" solutions but i couldn't apply them.
googling
trying some Intellij plugins.
trying to implement Gson TypeAdapters to no avail.

Comment: Relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776048 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36356019